# Move equation of plot on graph in Pages

Tags: pages, graph

This one has been irking me for quite a while. I've made a few plots in a Pages graph (as well as their R^2 values). It is especially useful to move the equations around, especially when there are multiple plots on the same graph.

I have tried everything that comes to my mind, such as clicking multiple times or dragging in strange ways, but it seems as though I can not move the equations on the graph at all. They remain on the top left corner. When I try clicking on them and dragging, the graph is moved instead of the equations.

Is it possible to move these equations around? The only other way I'm seeing it copying and pasting these equations into textboxes, but that likely would be a huge headache in terms of layouts as well as updating the graphs' data (and thus their trend line equations).

[Here](https://streamable.com/u9lev) is a video of the issue I am describing.

Comment: I *guess* your equations are included as `Inline` and are forced to follow your text flow. In this case change them for `Floating` so as to be able to place them above the correct plot.

Comment: @danielAzuelos it seems like the equations are a part of the graph, not another object themselves. So I can’t change the arrangement of the equations, but rather only the whole graph itself

Comment: I just made a test 2-Axis chart, and the labels are in a text box I have been able to move wherever I wanted by setting it as `Floating` object. I think a screen capture might help to understand your problem.

Comment: [Here](https://streamable.com/u9lev) is a video of the issue I'm talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a regression with the current version of Pages at the time of writing. It's not possible to move the equations in Pages 7.0.

Documents created with previous versions of Pages will preserve the equation position. If you still have the previous version of Pages, you can copy-paste the graph into the older version, move the equations and paste it back into the newer version.